# Error: Object doesn't support property or method datepicker - Jquery datepicker - IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

Jquery DatePicker works perfectly in Chrome, but throws '**Object doesn't support property or method datepicker**' in IE11. Tried various things but in vain. This doesn't seem to work in IE at all. Any kind of help appreciated.

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/JavaScript/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")%>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/JavaScript/jquery-ui.min.js")%>'></script>    
    <link href="StyleSheets/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">        
        $(function () {
            $('.txtStartDate').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1950:2100'
            });
            $('.txtEndDate').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1950:2100'
            });
        })

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="ContentMain" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main_ContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeout="36000" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <div class="sHeaderTitle">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text="Assign a Delegate"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <br />                       
        <table style="width: 100%;">                                    
            <tr id="trStartDate" runat="server">
                <td>
                    <strong>Start Date</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>:</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" Visible="false" CssClass="bluecontentbold" runat="server"></asp:Label>                       
                </td>                              
            </tr>
            <tr id="trEndDate" runat="server">
                <td>
                    <strong>End Date</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>:</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" CssClass="txtEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>      
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" Visible="false" CssClass="bluecontentbold" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                    
                </td>                                           
            </tr>                                          
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This might suggest that your jQuery ot jQuery UI scripts are not loading properly. What value do you see in the resulting Source? Are those sources loading properly?

Comment: @Twisty All jquery scripts are loading.